# export PHPMAIL 2.0 to outlook or suggestion on different service to use(wordpress plugin?)

Tags: php, wordpress, email

I'm helping a friend with his website, on the site he gives people a free email account. Everything works fine but he wants people to be able to export their mail to programs like outlook. He's using something called PHPMAIL 2.0 and I can't find any documentation on it.Does anyone have any experience with it?

So my question is can you export email from PHPMAIL 2.0? Or can you recommend another service maybe a plugin for Wordpress, that gives people an email account like username@mysite.com?

Comment: Do users actually have POP3 accounts on your friend's server?

Comment: It doesn't look like it, which is whats confusing me. There is one pop3 account 'catch@mysite.com'. I guess I don't understand how they have accounts like something@mysite.com but nothing shows up in cpanel

Answer (score 0):

If there's only one POP3 account, that probably means that your mail product is managing the E-Mails internally.

That most likely means the script is useless for what you want to do. For compatibility with E-Mail clients, you need to provide a POP3 or IMAP account - one per customer. If the existing system isn't equipped to do that, you'll need a whole new solution - quite possibly one that runs on a dedicated server, because programmatically creating and managing mail accounts is usually not possible on shared hosting.

Personally, I think providing full-fledged E-Mail services as a non-profit service is  a joyless business anyway. You become subject to all kinds of mail-related legislation, need to constantly work on your security, and get very little in return. I think this is something that should be left up to those who have the infrastructure to do it properly.